# JQuery Mobile default data-theme

Tags: javascript, mobile, themes, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know how to set a **default** data-theme for jquery-mobile?

It looks like it´s necessary to set the data-theme for every component.

Even when you set the data-theme for the page data-role it is not respected by loaded lists and other components.

Am I missing some page of the manual?

Answer (score 30):

Like Joel said, you have to overwrite the default values. At the moment it seems like there is no other way.

Take Joel's sample code:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Customize your custom-scripting.js

This is a sample code with a few more options you can configure:

```js
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

    // Navigation
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Go back";
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn      = true;
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme    = "d";

    // Page
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme = "a";  // Page header only
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme    = "c";
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme = "a";

    // Listviews
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.headerTheme = "a";  // Header for nested lists
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.theme           = "c";  // List items / content
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.dividerTheme    = "d";  // List divider

    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.splitTheme   = "c";
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.countTheme   = "c";
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterTheme = "c";
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterPlaceholder = "Filter data...";
});
```

There should be also other options like:

```
$.mobile.dialog.prototype.options.theme
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.menuPageTheme
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.overlayTheme
```

You might be able to find more settings here:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js

Comment: Hey, is there any way to add custom button in nested listview header, like above mentiond Back button...???

Comment: @umair.ali There is no 'built-in' way, that I know of. - You could extend the html structure via script and trigger jQuery Mobile to create the corresponding markup for you. -- Maybe it's better to create your own question on stackoverflow. If you are looking for navigation elements in general, then check out the new features of JQM like panels -- http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html

Answer (score 9):

For nested list views, to control the header theme you need to override the default option that is setting the nested header theme to blue.

To do this you simply add the following in between jquery loading and jquery.mobile.js loading.

example:

> Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately upon execution,
>   you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded.
>   Thus, we recommend linking to your JavaScript files in the following
>   order:
>
> ```
> <script src="jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
> <script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
> ```

So in "custom-scripting.js" put the following...

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
   $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.headerTheme = "a";
});
```

Where "a" is the theme you want to be applied to nested headers..

Or you can just override it in the jquery mobile source, search for "headerTheme" it will be around line 5020

Answer (score 7):

Themes a,b,c,d and e are all in the css file, if you want a custom theme you can use f-z, copy a and change it to your theme letter. add the data-theme="z" to your element

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="apply" data-theme="z">
...
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen you have to set a theme for a page div and it will be inherited inside.

Comment: naugtur, i´ve tried that, but in some cases, like nested lists, the theme configuration is not respected.

Comment: Try JQM alpha3 - it's been released today

Comment: I have the same problem, my collapsible elements all have the closing/opening icons with data-theme "d" and not c like I define for the page...

Comment: Setting data-theme="b" on a parent div changed most children for me.  Some things didn't though like my header.