# Inconsistent page thme with Jquery mobile nested list

Tags: jquery-mobile, nested-lists

In jquery mobile I have a nested list. 
When the nested list apears the page is not the same as the previous page.
The page showing the list  "1.html" is:
data-theme="a", with a nice header and footer.
The nested list looks like data-theme="d", no footer and has a back button - i would prefer a custom button?
Is there anyway to fixed this so the nested list page is consistent with its fathers' page?
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

A bug? What version of jQuery Mobile are you using? As of version 1.1.0 the back button in the header is disabled by default. Check out this example http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-nested.html

About your second question regarding the buttons, the footer and the themes.

To render a button, all you need to do is to put `data-role="button"` and for a theme add `data-theme="a"` to a link like this

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Link button</a>
```

To create the footer you need to place the following inside the page div:

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer content</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

As a demo, here is a page with the theme *e* applied:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="e">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <h1>Single page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
        <p>Some text here</p>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>       
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="e">
        <h4>Footer content</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

As a tip, you can look the examples here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/ and study the code by selecting "View Page Source" in your browser. This is the way I am learning JQM now.

Comment: You were right about the version. Upgrading solved partially the problem. Now how do I add my own button to the nested page and change its theme and add a footer?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your second question. If it was helpful can you mark my answer as _accepted answer_? Thanks! Check out here how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I thank you very much for your help. The partial solution is here on this great website:  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891906/jquery-mobile-default-data-theme/6906519#6906519)  I still have to figure out to change the page theme of the nested list

Comment: Please see: [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/controlling-header-theming-on-nested-lists)